# How to set value of an array object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

For example I have a matrix:

```
c1  c2  c3
1       2
```

value of matrix[0][1] is empty, I got output `null`, I want to set the value(string) of matrix[0][1] `n/a`, how should I do?

Comment: `matrix[0][1] = "n/a"`... Not sure what you are asking...

Comment: Can you post your code? Your question makes little sense and posting the code could help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need this:

```
if (matrix[0][1] == null)
{
    matrix[0][1] = 'n/a';
}
```

This condition is only for one index. Put the above condition in a loop and run it for all the indices of your matrix.
At the end of the day the nulls of your matrix will be replaced with "n/a"